# Android finish activity after callback is done

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, twitter, callback

In my android application i use signpost library to oauth sign in twitter.

and in code i try to catch callback using onNewIntent, but when i try to finish this activity - i see that there are some bugs - callback didn't go back to app when i write finish:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri ***) {
        twitterOauthHelper.saveKeyAndSecret(uri);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    } else {
        displayToast("Sign in: error occurred.");
    }
}
```

but how could i finish this activity only after callback from browser twitter sign in return's successful sign flag?

Comment: In which class is the call back and Where have you used this onNewIntent function?

Comment: @Darpan callback - i mean that signpost open webbrowser, and after successful sign in it redirect to activity Login (where this webbrowser is fired and where onNewIntent is)

Comment: Means when you successfully log in to twitter, you get a 'login successful' screen. There you wish to finish your `LoginActivity`.
PS - at 'login successful' I don't think you may be getting any callBack in android.

Comment: There you wish to finish your LoginActivity - yes. So how to be? )

Comment: What is written in your uri *** ? I guess it should be `(uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME))`  so that it could identify callBack.

Comment: @Darpan http://pastebin.com/b9X2eh18  here is whole class code

Comment: uri - means was auth successful or not

Comment: @Darpan so what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64764/discussion-between-darpan-and-brabertaser1992).

Comment: @Darpan added some details...

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer there is no errors

Comment: I do it like here: https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample

Comment: if after a successfull login you are redirected to the LoginActivity, then i think you could override the onRestoreInstanceState method and add this.finish() as it's last statement. Or you could still go by way of adding this.finish() to the onActivityResult callback method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Activity processing the returning Results you must add something like this;

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("extras", extras); //This is just an example extra.
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent); //This is the important part.
finish();
```

Once you have done this, on the preceding Activity (the one that will handle the result) you must do the following;

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) { 
            //Do something with "data"
}
```

Hope It helps, more info on [The Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Answer (score 0):

You mean that onNewIntent() is never called when login returns?
Try to check your AndroidManifest.xml. Does your Activity have `android:launchMode="singleTask"` flag?

Comment: all this work, not in this problem! check http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64764/discussion-between-darpan-and-brabertaser1992